# Solve a system of 2 congruences

Tags: systems-of-equations, congruences

How can I find the solution of the system:

$\begin{matrix} 4x+y\equiv22(\mod 26) \\ 19x+y\equiv1(\mod 26)  \end{matrix}$

Using the following theorem? I don't know how to work with the $\bar{\Delta}$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This theorem gives the solution explicitly. Just put in your specific values.

Comment: Yes, off course, but I don't know how to work with the Δ¯

Comment: Is $b$ fixed or is it a variable (like $y$ in the theorem)?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, it's a y!

Comment: Well then, we have $m=26$ and $\Delta=4\cdot 1-1\cdot 19=-15\equiv 11\pmod{26}$. So can you find the multiplicative inverse of $11$ in $\Bbb Z_{26}$? Note: this inverse will exist since $\gcd(26,11)=1$.

Comment: Notice: $26\cdot 3=78$ and $7\cdot 11=77$

Comment: Yes, I found that Δ≡11(mod26). The multiplicative intense off 11? I can't find it so quickly.

Comment: As per my hint, we have $$26(3)+11(-7)=1$$can you read off the inverse from here?

Comment: Sorry I don't see it. I'm searching for an integer A such that 11*A≡1(mod26). Isn't that the definition of the inverse of 11?

Comment: Yes. The equation $26(3)+11(-7)=1$ modulo $26$ is $11(-7)\equiv 1\pmod{26}$.

Comment: Oh, Ok, now I understand your way of thinking. But how can I use that inverse -7 to calculate  Δ¯?

Comment: $-7$ is $\Delta^{-1}$. Note that $-7\equiv 19\pmod{26}$.